# Interpolating variables into a string

Tags: javascript, react-native, string-interpolation

Although an experienced programmer I am completely new to js and react.

I am trying to use the `react-native-svg` component `Path` within a component of my own. All is clear with the example, but it uses a string literal for the coordinates. E.g.:

```
<Path d="M 10 20 L 30 40" stroke="red" />
```

However I want to use coordinates from my component's props `x1`, `y2`, `x2`, `y2` instead of literals but I can't figure out how to plant them into the quoted string along with the various characters of which `M` and `L` are examples.

Comment: You need a generic path component with props, or this exact path with different numbers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668025/react-jsx-access-props-in-quotes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using ES2015 features, [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would be a possible approach, e.g.:

```
<Path
    d={`M ${this.props.x1} ${this.props.y1} L ${this.props.x2} ${this.props.y2}`}
    stroke="red"
/>
```

Note the backticks instead of quotes.

Comment: This works, thanks. Is there any way of viewing the resulting complete Path tag that the code above builds? Something analogous to View Source in for a web page in a browser.

Comment: You can use template strings like other expressions, they evaluate to a string. I.e.: `const path = \`...\`; console.log(path); return <Path d={path} ... />`

Answer (score 2):

This look like a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425719/react-composite-key-for-a-list-of-list) that I had.  You can pass in an array of items and join them to create your string.

```
<Path d={['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2].join(' ')} stroke="red" />
```